# Breaking values into categories

Tags: r

Please I need help in fixing the code below, i am trying to break the data into 4 categories based on the quantile they fall in but the output is turns out to be something different.

```
for(i in data[[2]]){
 if(i>=min(data$PI) & i<quantile(data$PI, probs = .25)){
        data[[2]] = "Low income"
    }

   else if (i>=quantile(data$PI, probs = .25) & i<quantile(data$PI, probs = .5)){
        data[[2]] = "Average income"
    }

   else if(i>=quantile(data$PI, probs = .5) & i<quantile(data$PI, probs = .75)){
        data[[2]] = "High income"
    }
    else{
        data[[2]] = "Very high income"
    }

}
```

output after runing the code below gives only one category instead of 4

```
table(data[[2]])
```

Low income 
      1050

Comment: Since you didn't provide a minimal dataset, all I can offer is this: use the `cut` function instead.

Comment: You keep re-assigning data[[2]] to a single value. The result is whatever the last assignment was. If data[[2]] is a vector, you are just overwriting it with a single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Edward, uou can use `cut` or `findInterval` to do this without a loop. Try :

```
data$category <- c("Low income","Average income","High income","Very high income")
                 [findInterval(data$PI, quantile(data$PI, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))) + 1]
```

This assigns the value "Low income", "Average income" etc to `category` column based on the range in which the `PI` value lies.